# group and pattern matching in java

Tags: java, regex

How I can differentiate this string with Matcher and Pattern class?

I tried like this

```
String question="A: this is data i want first  B: this is data i want second  C: this is data i want  third A: this is data i want first  B: this is data i want second  C: this is data i want  third ";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("A:(.*?)B:(.*?)C:(.*?)A:", Pattern.DOTALL | Pattern.MULTILINE);           
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(question);
while (m.find()) {
    m.group(1);
    m.group(2);
    m.group(3);
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. What qre you trying to match on your string? Is it by the letters start? Is it by the sentence? Add the desired result. It will help clarify what you need!

Comment: A: this is data i want first  B: 
I wants data between [A: - B:] [B: - C:] ...... from question

Comment: Why do you want to use a regex? Are you sure your input data is part of a regular language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit of a hack but works if you don't find a better answer:

Use this regex:

```
A:(.*?)B:(.*?)C:(.*?)(?=A:)
```

But you'll have to append a delimiter to the string (your **question** variable):

```
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(question + "A:");
```

Used with println:

```
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
    System.out.println(m.group(2));
    System.out.println(m.group(3));
}
```

It outputs:

> this is data i want first
>    this is data i want second
>    this is data i want  third
>    this is data i want first
>    this is data i want second
>    this is data i want  third

Answer (score 0):

As this requires a context, you could use a parser like [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) or you could code your own solution.

I would go with something like:

```
SplitterStringMatcher matcher = new SplitterStringMatcher {
    private char delimiter = 'A';
    // return the count of characters matched, 0 if none
    @Override public int matches(String str, int pos) {
        if (str.length() > pos + 1
                && str.charAt(pos) == delimiter
                && str.charAt(pos + 1) == ':') {
            if (++delimiter == 'D') { delimiter = 'A'; }
            return 2;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}

String[] strs = Splitter.split(question, matcher);
```

Then you implement the `Splitter`... it must split the input at every position `matches()` returns a value greater than 0 and skipping the number of characters returned.

You can also improve the matcher to match blanks before the delimiter letter and after the `':'`.